# How to get the probability/closeness of a sample belonging to a specific cluster?

Tags: classification, clustering, unsupervised-learning, k-means, cosine-distance

I'm new to this so please let me know if my logic of comparing `cosine similarity` and `k-means` is incorrect

I got a set of `4 clusters` from `k-means` and now I'm interested in the `Cluster No. 1`. For this cluster, I take the `average of all values for each column` and keep it aside.

Now, I have a test sample, for which I run `k-means prediction` and I get output as `1`, meaning it belongs to `Cluster No. 1` which is good for me but my use-case here was to calculate that even if that sample didn't belong to `Cluster 1`, how close was it to falling in that `Cluster No. 1`

Hence, to resolve this I thought of doing a `cosine similarity` between my test sample and the one where I take `average of all values for each column`. Now, in this case, I get a similarity of just `5%`

I'm not sure, for my use-case `i.e.  (Getting the probability/closeness of a sample belonging to a specific cluster)` which is a better interpretation for me?

I know I can use the cluster labels as `y` variables and make `multi-class classification model` but I want to keep it as `un-supervised` as possible. Please guide

Comment: This might answer your question directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54240144/distance-between-nodes-and-the-centroid-in-a-kmeans-cluster

Answer (score 1):

Try Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) as it is similar to KMeans, but differs in a few ways. In a nutshell think of KMeans as a hard clustering model where each sample is assigned to only one cluster, whereas GMM is a soft clustering technique that calculates the density (probability) of each Gaussian mixture (which can be considered as clusters) containing the data point in question. You can get both labels and probability scores from the model. Try it and see if it helps in your case. It is available from the SciKit Learn library.

Another approach in case if you have to stick to KMeans could be:

1. Take the cluster centers from the KMeans model.
2. Take your test sample vector and pass these as parameters to the softmax function to get the probability score for all the cluster centers per sample.

Comment: Re. Another approach #2.: Did you mean to pass distances between samples and cluster centers to softmax? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Agreed with @mac13k : it is unclear in (2) what you sending in to "the" softmax.  Also: there is no `softmax` applied anyways in classical k-means: they're just a euclidean distance so can you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

Similarity when clustering is used is usually based on same distance metric as the one used to cluster the data.

Then to test similarity of a random sample to the cluster assigned one can compute the average distance of the sample with all points in that same cluster.

This average distance (sometimes also normalized) is a similarity or fitness measure.

PS cosine similarity requires data to satisfy certain properties (eg be normalized) to make sense.